# How do I use the custom publisher prefix when creating a new entity field in CRM 2013?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to create a new field on a custom entity in a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 solution.

When I create the field the name is prefixed with an static "new_".

I can see that there is a default publisher with this prefix and a custom one with another prefix.

How do I create this new field with the custom publisher prefix.

Is my user somehow connected to a publisher which I need to change or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working in a solution is best practice.

Any entity/field created in a solution will use the publisher prefix of the publisher associated with the solution.

There is a lot of detail [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334576.aspx).

There is a publisher record associated with a solution.

The prefix that is used is take from the publisher associated with the solution you are working in.

You can change the prefix of the default solution's publisher, but I think it is much better to create a new solution.

Solutions can help to bundle up customizations and keep things organized.

I recommend using an unmanged solution unless you have a specific requirement for a managed solution.